# How can i get date by position (first, second, third November) using Python?

Tags: python, calendar

**I need a help for get a date from a position in a month.**

For example:

- The 4º day, considering just the workdays (days except saturday and sunday) on a week in November 2022
  is 2022/11/07.
- The 21º day, considering just the workdays (days except saturday and sunday) on a week
  in November 2022 is 2022/11/29.

I have:

```
import calendar

c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)

year = 2022; month = 11

monthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
ordinal_date = [day for week in monthcal for day in week if \
                day.month == month]

 ordinal_date:
    [datetime.date(2022, 11, 1),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 2),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 3),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 4),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 5),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 6),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 7),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 8),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 9),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 10),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 11),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 12),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 13),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 14),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 15),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 16),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 17),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 18),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 19),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 20),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 21),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 22),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 23),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 24),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 25),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 26),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 27),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 28),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 29),
     datetime.date(2022, 11, 30)]
```

When i do that, for the eighth workday, i have the wrong result:

```
ordinal_date[8]:
datetime.date(2022, 11, 9)
```

The result that i need for the eighth workday should be:

```
datetime.date(2022, 11, 10)
```

How can i get only de weekdays based on position ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If by "workdays" you mean "every day except Sunday", you can simply change your code to:

```
ordinal_date = [day for week in monthcal for day in week if \
                day.month == month and day.weekday() != 0]
```

Comment: Unfortunelly your suggestion not works,  Workdays i mean Business Day. But, thanks.

Comment: I think you should be able to adapt my code to exclude Saturdays and Sundays. You just need to exclude weekdays 5 and 6. The principle is the same. But I think you have one misconception: `ordinal_date[8]` will not give you the eighth day, but the nineth. Lists start at index 0, so index 8 is actually the 9th element.

Answer (score 0):

I founded this solution working with **calendar**, **holidays**, **numpy**, **Window**:

```
import calendar
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import Window
import holidays


# Import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create SparkSession 
spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .master("local[1]") \
      .appName("SparkByExamples.com") \
      .getOrCreate() 

 c = calendar.Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)

year = 2022; month = 11

monthcal = c.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
ordinal_date = [day for week in monthcal for day in week if \
                day.month == month]

is_busday = [np.is_busday(a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) for a in ordinal_date]


busday_list = []
i = 0

while i < len(is_busday):
    busday_list.append(str(is_busday[i]))
    i = i + 1

columns = ['date','is_busday']       

all_days_verified = spark.createDataFrame(zip(ordinal_date,busday_list), columns)
all_days_verified.show()
+----------+---------+
|      date|is_busday|
+----------+---------+
|2022-11-01|     True|
|2022-11-02|     True|
|2022-11-03|     True|
|2022-11-04|     True|
|2022-11-05|    False|
|2022-11-06|    False|
|2022-11-07|     True|
|2022-11-08|     True|
|2022-11-09|     True|
|2022-11-10|     True|
|2022-11-11|     True|
|2022-11-12|    False|
|2022-11-13|    False|
|2022-11-14|     True|
|2022-11-15|     True|
|2022-11-16|     True|
|2022-11-17|     True|
|2022-11-18|     True|
|2022-11-19|    False|
|2022-11-20|    False|
```

**Excluding local hollidays:**

```
holidays_list = holidays.country_holidays('BR', subdiv='SP')

hollidays_days = []
hollidays_sp_br = []

for hollidays in holidays_list['2022-01-01': '2022-12-31']:
    hollidays_days.append(hollidays)
    hollidays_sp_br.append('holliday')
    
columns = ['hollidays_dates','is_holliday_sp_br']  
hollidays_spbr = spark.createDataFrame(zip(hollidays_days,hollidays_sp_br), columns)
hollidays_spbr.show()
+---------------+-----------------+
|hollidays_dates|is_holliday_sp_br|
+---------------+-----------------+
|     2022-01-01|         holliday|
|     2022-03-01|         holliday|
|     2022-03-02|         holliday|
|     2022-04-15|         holliday|
|     2022-04-17|         holliday|
|     2022-04-21|         holliday|
|     2022-05-01|         holliday|
|     2022-06-16|         holliday|
|     2022-07-09|         holliday|
|     2022-09-07|         holliday|
|     2022-10-12|         holliday|
|     2022-11-02|         holliday|
|     2022-11-15|         holliday|
|     2022-12-25|         holliday|
+---------------+-----------------+
```

**Making a complete calender:**

```
complete_calendar = all_days_verified.join(hollidays_spbr,all_days_verified.date ==  hollidays_spbr.hollidays_dates,"left")

complete_calendar = complete_calendar.na.fill(value= 'is_not_local_holliday', subset=["is_holliday_sp_br"])

complete_calendar.show(30)
+----------+---------+---------------+--------------------+
|      date|is_busday|hollidays_dates|   is_holliday_sp_br|
+----------+---------+---------------+--------------------+
|2022-11-29|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-21|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-20|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-01|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-23|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-10|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-28|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-22|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-24|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-04|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-14|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-07|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-03|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-11|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-13|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-09|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-12|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-19|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-26|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-27|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-06|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-16|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-08|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-17|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-18|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-05|    False|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-02|     True|     2022-11-02|            holliday|
|2022-11-25|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-30|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-15|     True|     2022-11-15|            holliday|
+----------+---------+---------------+--------------------+
```

**Filtering by just business days, excluding local hollidays:**

```
only_busday = complete_calendar.filter((complete_calendar.is_busday == "True") & (complete_calendar.is_holliday_sp_br == "is_not_local_holliday"))

only_busday = only_busday.sort("date")

only_busday.show(30)
+----------+---------+---------------+--------------------+
|      date|is_busday|hollidays_dates|   is_holliday_sp_br|
+----------+---------+---------------+--------------------+
|2022-11-01|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-03|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-04|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-07|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-08|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-09|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-10|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-11|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-14|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-16|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-17|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-18|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-21|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-22|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-23|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-24|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-25|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-28|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-29|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
|2022-11-30|     True|           null|is_not_local_holl...|
+----------+---------+---------------+--------------------+
```

**Ordering dates and creating order number for that dates:**

```
df_index = only_busday.select("*").withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())


window = Window.orderBy(F.col('id'))

df_final = df_index.withColumn('order_busday', F.row_number().over(window))

local_busday = df_final.select('date','order_busday')

local_busday.show()

+----------+------------+
|      date|order_busday|
+----------+------------+
|2022-11-01|           1|
|2022-11-03|           2|
|2022-11-04|           3|
|2022-11-07|           4|
|2022-11-08|           5|
|2022-11-09|           6|
|2022-11-10|           7|
|2022-11-11|           8|
|2022-11-14|           9|
|2022-11-16|          10|
|2022-11-17|          11|
|2022-11-18|          12|
|2022-11-21|          13|
|2022-11-22|          14|
|2022-11-23|          15|
|2022-11-24|          16|
|2022-11-25|          17|
|2022-11-28|          18|
|2022-11-29|          19|
|2022-11-30|          20|
+----------+------------+
```

**So as we can see, the twentieth busday on november 2022 is 2022-11-30, the tenth day november 2022  is november 2022.
Maybe there's another way to do that, but i found just this solution.**